# I'm getting error when I import stream from tweepy

Tags: python

I get this error message when I try `from tweepy import stream`

```
ImportError: cannot import name stream
```

knowing that I installed tweepy on my python

Comment: Please share some code with us.

Comment: As Alec mentioned in answer you propably have issue with import. Take look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867504 they are using some Stream from tweepy that might be the one you want

Comment: import tweepy
from tweepy import stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it would really help to see your code, it looks like you're using the line

```
from tweepy import stream
```

correct?

When I look at the tweepy tests, it looks like Stream should be capitalized. Check out this page for an example:

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py

When importing in Python (and with all things in Python) case matters. So try changing the line to

```
from tweepy import Stream
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a line of code that reads:

```
import stream
```

somewhere and Python has no idea what you are on about. - That is why you have this error.

For more help we need more code, ideally your python path too.

Comment: I installed tweepy and wrote those codes: import tweepy, from tweepy import stream

Comment: @GalalAli I take no credit for this (the answer from ... I'm not writing that out - mentions it) try a capital S